# icecast returns text/html instead of audio/mpeg

Tags: http-headers, esp8266, icecast, request-headers, internet-radio

I've build a simple internet radio using ESP8266+VS1053. It works.
The query sent to icecast server looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Windows-Media-Player/10.00.00.1111
Host: 66.85.88.242
Icy-Metadata:1
Accept: audio/mpeg,audio/aacp
Connection: keep-alive
```

SOME stations works fine, while others returns html instead of stream data. For example:
SheRadio: http://66.85.88.242:8136/1139_128 -- returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 501
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2018 22:05:43 GMT
Server: Icecast 2.4.0-kh3
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
Connection: Close
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT


DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
    <title>Icecast Streaming Media Server</title>
```

(and so on)
instead of:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast DNAS/posix(linux x64) v2.5.5.733<BR>
Accept-Ranges:none
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate,max-age=0
Connection:close
icy-name:Goldradio Network
icy-genre:60s, 70s, 80s, Top 40, Oldies
icy-br:24
icy-sr:16000
icy-url:http://www.goldradio.org.uk
icy-pub:1
content-type:audio/mpeg
icy-metaint:8192
X-Clacks-Overhead:GNU Terry Pratchett
```

sent by other stations.

I was completely unable to understand why some worked and some not.
Thanks in advance for any help/ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you **MUST** provide the proper path in your HTTP GET request!

`GET / HTTP/1.1` is **NOT** requesting 'http://66.85.88.242:8136/1139_128', but 'http://66.85.88.242:8136/'. The latter *is* 'text/html' content.

This can be easily verified using:

`curl -v --user-agent "Windows-Media-Player/10.00.00.1111" -H "Icy-Metadata: 1" -H "Accept: audio/mpeg,audio/aacp" http://66.85.88.242:8136/ >/dev/null`

vs.

`curl -v --user-agent "Windows-Media-Player/10.00.00.1111" -H "Icy-Metadata: 1" -H "Accept: audio/mpeg,audio/aacp" http://66.85.88.242:8136/1139_128 >/dev/null`

Not sure how it is for ESP8266, but at least for the ESP32, libcurl builds perfectly fine and would be my preferred option for handling HTTP requests instead of error prone hand crafting.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Had to change the headers to:

`GET /chill HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Windows-Media-Player/10.00.00.1111
Host: 203.146.251.172
Icy-Metadata:1
Accept: audio/mpeg,audio/aacp
Connection: keep-alive`

(for a station like `203.146.251.172:80/chill` )